# Self-adjoint elements that commutes and positive

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, functional-calculus

I asked a question earlier regarding self-adjoint elements. I will ask a similar question again.

**Claim:** I have $0\leq A_1\leq A_2$ for self-adjoint elements $A_1,A_2$ in $C^\ast$-algebra.  If $0\leq A_1\leq A_2$ and where $A_1$ and $A_2$ commute, then we have $A_1^k\leq A_2^k$ for every positive integer $k$.

**Idea:** Can we show it by considering the following, i.e. if there are positive elements $B_j$ for $1\leq j \leq m$ with $$0\leq A_1\leq B_1\leq B_2\leq \cdots \leq B_m\leq A_2$$ so that any two neighbors in this list above commute, then $A^k\leq B^k$ for any positive integer $k$. How would one attack this? If we can’t how would we else show the claim?

Answer (score 1):

I can't follow your idea but here is a proof.

The two positive elements $A:=A_1$ and $B:=A_2-A_1$ commute hence
$$A_2^k-A_1^k=\sum_{j=1}^k\binom kjA^{j/2}B^{k-j}A^{j/2}\ge0.$$

Comment: Okay interesting. How do you know it would be greater than zero? Is it because of my statement?

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand this question. I "knew" nothing, I simply rewrote and proved your claim. May be unconsciently by analogy with real numbers, taking advantage of the commutation hypothesis

Comment: Okay I'm glad that you wrote something. I'm trying to learn functional analysis as a autodidact and I have a lot of ideas when reading. Let me rewrite it.
Suppose that $0\le A_1\leq A_2$ for self-adjoint elements $A_1,A_2$ in a $C^\ast$-algebra. If $0\leq A_1\leq A_2$ and $A_1$ and $A_2$ commute, then $A_1^k\leq A_2^k$ for every positive integer $k$. More generally; show that if there are positive elements $B_j$ where $1\leq j\leq m$ with $0\leq A_1\leq B_1\leq B_2\leq \cdots \leq B_m\leq A_2$ so that any two neighbors in the list commute. Then $A_1^k\leq A_2^k$ for any positive integer $k$.

Comment: Yes this corollary is straightforward.